# Is it preferable to pre-calculate condition statement part of for loop?

Tags: java, optimization, coding-style

For example

```
int offset = getOffset();
int count = getCount();
int limit = count + offset;
for (int i; i < limit; i++) {}
```

is more preferable to

```
int offset = getOffset();
int count = getCount();
for (int i; i < offset + count; i++) {}
```

If Java VM does the addition on each iteration, that sounds like quite an overhead. But if the complier is smart enough to limit the addition to single time, I'd like to keep my code short.

Comment: you need to evaluate it every iteration. If you evaluate it once it would cause infinite loop

Comment: Any decent optimizer will probably be able to do this for you. However, since this is a very minor "text addition", you may as well do it yourself and remove all doubts (as well as the need to compile your code under optimization, which yields the (possibly undesired) effect of making debugging much harder).

Comment: wardziniak//I mean the addtion part of the condition test, not the condion test itself. and yes, that would make an infinite loop

Comment: You want to know if doing this `int limit = count + offset;` is better than loop through this `offset + count`. For a minor addition, it is shouldn't even matter.  Instead, if your question is looping through `getOffset() + getCount()` better than looping through `offset + count` then it depends on your programming logic. Do these methods return different values each time they are called OR do they perform some heavy operation but return same values?

Comment: More important is to make your variables `final` so that the reader can trivially see that the bound doesn’t change.

Comment: I would definitly not go with getOffset() + getCount(). If they change in real time, it will need some synchronization mechanism. Simple codes like that will be very dangerous.

Answer (score 6):

> Premature optimization is the root of all evil.

Don't worry about this now.

---

When you extract the addition part out of the loop, it would indeed be evaluated only once. Some compilers may be smart enough to optimise this as well, but some may not.

The time it takes for almost all CPUs to do addition of 32 bit integers is *incredibly* small. If you used a profiler and found that the for loop condition is *indeed* causing performance problems, then you should take the addition out and see if it helps. But there is little point in worrying about it when you don't even have/haven't found a problem.

---

So for now, write your code according to what you are thinking in your head. For me, for example, if I am thinking "now I need to repeat this (offset + count) times...", I will write

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < offset + count ; i++)
```

If I am thinking "now I need to calculate how many times we loop for, and then I will loop that many times", then I would write:

```
int limit = offset + count;
for (int i = 0 ; i < limit ; i++)
```

Comment: Perfectely aggre with you i will just add that perfomance issue is often the last issue you will handle and improving perfomance is not someting you read the code but using some profiling tool to target the most important latency durring your execution

Comment: Perfectly agree with Arnault. Whenever I used my profiler to find out what part of the code was slowing down my application, I **always** was surprised. From reading the code you **never** find the place worth optimizing.

Comment: That is a good idiom for real developers, but I think my question more belong to the computer theory. Something like which algorythm is better stuff. And even if I weren't consider about the optimization, I still have to <b>choose</b> which style to go with anyway.

Comment: @JavaToTavaL When I write code, I just write the logic in my head out. I am usually unconscious about the _exact_ code I'm writing. If I am thinking "now we need to repeat this (offset + count) times..." then I would write the addition inside the loop header. If I am thinking "Now let's calculate the amount of times that I need to repeat this", then I would write the addition outside the loop header. Just choose whatever makes sense in your head.

Comment: I rather appreciate your comment above. The idiom part itself wasn't the answer I was looking for, though, so if you reqoute your comment as a seperate answer, I may accept it, instead. Thank you.

Comment: @JavaToTavaL Edited.